Logistic Regression - 2 different Independent variable's dummies have perfect correlation
Let's say I have 2 variables in my model:
Credit_Card_Debt - with the dummies 'No credit cards','0-100','101-1000','1000+' - 1000+ is the reference category
Number_of_credit_cards - with the dummies 'No credit cards','1',2+ - 2+ is the reference category
Now the dummies Credit_Card_Debt:No credit cards and Number_of_credit_cards:'No credit cards' will have a correlation of 1, when 1 of them is 1 then other one will be 1 by definition.
Am I allowed to keep both of these dummies in the model? I've always been told that dummies with a correlation of 1 are not allowed in the model

Why do you have dummies for the first? Can you get data on total debt in dollars? (or Euros or whatever currency you are using).  Categorizing a continuous variable is almos always a mistake.

Could you tell me why it's a mistake? I use it to eliminate variance mostly and make the data easier to work with without the need for any transformations.

Because it increases type 1 and type 2 error and assumes that something special happens at the breaks.  And it doesn't avoid "the need for any transformation", it IS a transformation. I wrote a whole blog post on this.  https://medium.com/@peterflom/what-happens-when-we-categorize-an-independent-variable-in-regression-77d4c5862b6c

I see, I'll read it after creating an account on medium. Thanks. What about my original question, if we assume that instead of continuous those are categorical variables (occupation with missing being no data) and (Country with missing being no data) missing dummies once again have correlation of 1- why is it a bad idea to have both missing dummies in the model

Your original question is a duplicate, I am sure. But I can't find the duplicate question. Someone else probably will.

What do you mean by "in my model"? Are you using both of these variables as regressors? If they're regressands, consider hurdle models.

Some similar posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577919/how-to-solve-perfect-collinearity-with-one-level-of-categorical-variable,
